# Как поставить таблицу по центру, но чтобы она начиналась сверху?

Tags: html, css

[image]Как поставить таблицу по центру, но чтобы она начиналась сверху? А то я поставил

```
 <table align="center">
```

и он берет с центра экрана строит его. А я хочу чтобы начиналась сверху, а сама была в центре. Вот так хочу сделать

```
 |xx|yy|zz|
 |xx|yy|zz|
 |xx|yy|zz|
```

Вот столб ХХ сделал, а щас хочу YY сделать, но он ставится по центру, т.е на место второго YY, а я хочу с первого YY позицию ставить

Comment: @navi1893, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: вот, выложил фотку. Хочу сделать так, чтобы красный прямоугольник поднялся наверх, к синей линии. Ставлю margin-top, ничего не происходит. Он не поднимается @Dazar

Comment: @navi1893, на картинке две разные таблицы?

Comment: @Dazar да, разные они

Answer (score 2):

Тут какой-то парадокс или я не правильно понял. Таблица строится по центру, но я хочу чтобы она была по центру =)). Насчет того, что она начиналась с вверху, для родителя ставим такой параметр - `vertical-align:top;`

Answer (score 2):

Раз таблицы разные, то для того, чтобы они оказались на одном уровне, первой таблице задать стиль `style='float: left;'`

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы выставить два и более **блочных элемента** в один ряд, необходимо, чтобы все они (кроме последнего) **«плавали»**: для них должно быть указано CSS-свойство `float: left` или `float: right` в зависимости от того, куда эти элементы должны "плыть" — влево или вправо.

Вот тут, например, написано более подробно: http://htmlbook.ru/css/float.

**В вашем случае** достаточно указать блоку слева свойство `float: left`, чтобы он "пустил" центральный блок на свой уровень.

Кроме того, можно попробовать поставить *отрицательное* значение `margin-top`. Но это скорее хак, и лучше обойтись без этого.

Другое возможное, но устаревшее решение — объединить элементы невидимой таблицей, и вставить их в качестве ячеек этой таблицы. Правда, такое сейчас считается моветоном.

Comment: не необходимо, есть еще display: inline* 

насчет моветона - это слово для быдлокодеров придуманное, чтобы они не делали глупостей. я не про верстку таблицей, а вообще.

Comment: @eicto, действительно. Но если превратить блок в строковый элемент, могут возникнуть разные неприятные эффекты.

Answer (score 2):

Вот никак не могу понять: отчего все так ненавидят таблицы? Я понимаю, если речь идет о макете с килотоннами ячеек, с кашей из атрибутов rowspan/colspan. Когда в итоге получается верстка из сплошных таблиц, содержащие таблицы, таблицы, ..., таблицы. Вот это — моветон. А использовать таблицу там, где это действительно необходимо — не преступление, на мой взгляд. Тем более, когда на языке вертится: «это будет три столбца». Столбца! Так почему бы не использовать? Зачем прибегать к какому-то хаку в виде обтекания справа, когда нужно сделать 2 колонки? Что, много разметки? Ничего не много! Браузерам уже давно плевать: спозиционировать им 1 элемент или 4. 100M сетевухе уже тоже давно плевать, в отличие от 56K-модема. И редакторы с подсветкой синтаксиса есть — не заблудишься в разметке.

Да и ладно, у нас же теперь есть неплохая возможность «семантической» разметки. Хотя, она таковой и была всегда, просто для искушенных верстальщиков добавили еще элементов — для нормального структурирования.

Но еще у нас же есть чудо CSS, да? Можно же и не писать `<table>`, при этом заставляя резметку вести себя как таблица.

http://jsfiddle.net/qJdy4/1/

---

Осмелюсь, все же, предположить, что автор сам употребил «таблица» там, где ей в самом деле не место. Я подумал, что нужна просто страница с перечнем песен [обложка,название,плеер] в стиле плиток по сетке. Тогда, возможно, подойдет [эта заготовка](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw98S/).

Comment: @Bars, именно поэтому в своём ответе я и сказал ещё и про этот способ. Действительно, иногда может быть эффективно поставить таблицу и ничего зазорного в этом не будет. Вопрос выбора инструментария.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я написал этот ответ не от желания содрать ваше альтернативное предложение о таблице, а ради того чтобы заострить внимание на том, что тут, с моей точки зрения, нужно *именно табличное представление,* а не финт с обтеканием.